# Are "right now" and "currently" exchangeably here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

Chapter 2 of the book "C++ Primer Plus, 6th Edition by Stephen Prata (2012)" says

> **Right now** the main point to remember is that C++ syntax requires you to begin the definition of the main() function with this header:int main().This chapter discusses the function header syntax in more detail later, in the section “Functions,” but for those who can’t put their curiosity on hold, here’s a preview.

In [Oxford dict](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/currently) "right now" and "currently" are synonyms.

Are "right now" and "currently" exchangeably here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They *are* synonymous, but they have slightly different idiomatic usage.

"Right now" very specifically refers to *this moment in time*.

"Currently" is used in a broader sense, for *ongoing* matters that have already begun in the past - for example, the term "*current affairs*" refers to news bulletins that cover what has happened in a day or even a longer period such as a week. The latest edition of a monthly magazine may be termed "the current edition", even though it could be 29 days old.

In your text, I feel that "right now" is **not** interchangeable with "currently". It is telling you that, *at the precise moment you are reading it*, you should remember this main point.

> Right now the main point to remember is that...

It reads as an *instruction*, advising you to remember a particular point *now*. Your quote even says that other matters will be discussed *later* in the chapter, which is why I am certain that "right now" refers to your present position in the book and not some real-world climate. As a learning manual, it is speaking to you very directly and meant to be read in order so that you learn the subject in a linear fashion.

Consider this order:

> Turn around right now.

You can't say "turn around *currently*" - that doesn't make any sense.

An example where they *are* interchangeable:

> - *Currently*, there are 4 major armed conflicts happening in the world.
> - *Right now*, there are 4 major armed conflicts happening in the world.

They are interchangeable in this context because the events they refer to are both *ongoing* (and so "current") and occurring "right now", at this moment in time.

Comment: I beg to differ. I might be wrong, but if *currently* tends to be used for ongoing matters (as you said), it can be used instead, given that *reading the book* is an ongoing matter.

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra It reads like an order. "Right now, you should do this...". If somebody said "turn around right now!" you can't swap the term with "currently", can you? "Turn around *currently*" doesn't make any sense. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: I totally agree that "Turn around *currently*" doesn't make any sense, because that's an order. However, "The main point  to remember..." is not an *order*, is it? I, personally, take it as an advice or sort of "how to".

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra Ok, perhaps "order" is the wrong term - but it is an *instruction manual*. It is meant to be read as if it is being spoken to you, so when it says "right now.... this", and "later... that" (which it does, see my latest revision) it *is* referring to the moment that you read it, not just a current, ongoing situation.

Comment: I get what you're saying, I just see it differently. To *me*, it does make sense to use either one. Anyway, thanks for clarifying and +1 for a good, detailed answer.

Comment: @Astralbee Thank you! Your answer helps me a lot! How about think of "Right now" has a meaning of "time point" which "currently" don't have. "Turn around right now" means "Turn around" in a few seconds and "currently" does not have this meaning.

Answer (score 0):

They are pretty much synonyms. You could substitute **Currently** for **Right now** in that passage with little change of meaning. The difference is one of those subtleties of idiomatic English.

**Currently** is defined as "[at the present time; now](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/currently)" and can mean a period of time upto and including the present. For example

> **Currently** I am delivering potatoes.

You may not be actually delivering a potato as you speak, but you have been doing so very recently, this week for example. You are in the middle of the potato delivery process.

**Right now** emphasises that you are [talking about the present moment](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/right-now)

> **Right now** I am delivering potatoes

I've got potatoes in my hand and I'm giving them to a customer.

Comment: It really depends on the ***context*** - if you'd been talking about the various jobs you've had over *decades* of past employment, ***Right now I'm delivering potatoes*** could reasonably be used / interpreted as meaning I've [only] been delivering potatoes ***for the past few hours / days / weeks / months*** (probably not ***years***, but that couldn't always be ruled out). In other contexts it could mean you've only been doing those deliveries (and/or will continue doing so) for a matter of ***minutes / seconds***. As ever, context is everything.